# Is there a book explicitly about TeX programming?

Tags: plain-tex

I'd like to learn basic TeX programming (as a programming language instead of a tool of typeset) systematically, but I find "the Tex Book" by Knuth spends much time on typeset matter. Is there a book that focuses on explicit Tex programming and goes deeper?

Comment: Do you mean something like [TeX by topic](https://ftpmirror1.infania.net/mirror/CTAN/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)?

Comment: I skimmed the contents and it seems to be the right book. Great thanks!

Comment: Actually all the answers here are already in [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?rq=1) anyway.

Answer (score 6):

[The TeXbook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) is still a good source for pure TeX programming; just skip all the chapters that you don't care about.

[Notes On Programming in TeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/TeX-programming-notes.pdf) is pretty much exactly what you describe. It's fairly short, and not really suited to a beginner, but it is very good.

[TeX in a Nutshell](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/tex-nutshell/tex-nutshell.pdf) is also a very good. It spends a lot of time describing how boxes and glue work, but I wouldn't really call this "typesetting".

[@mickep mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682549/is-there-a-book-explicitly-about-tex-programming#comment1693509_682549) [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf). This is a good reference manual, but you really wouldn't want to use this to learn anything for the first time.

The [macros category of TUGboat](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html#CatTAGMacros) is also a good source. These are all short articles generally on a single topic, but they often discuss material that you can't find anywhere else. Some of these are intended for beginners, while others are intended for *very* advanced users.

In general though, I wouldn't recommend learning how to do pure "programming" tasks in TeX. If you ever need to do programming in TeX, you will have a much better time using either use Lua (via LuaTeX) or expl3.

Comment: It is of course a pure matter of opinion but using expl3 without having a deep understanding of the core TeX concepts which are nicely (to my mind) exposed in TeX by Topic is a kind of renouncement.  There are actually further things needed beyond TeX by Topic because the latter does not cover the e-TeX expansion (lapsus, I meant extensions, but some have a lot to do with expansion...) which are crucial to many expl3 constructs.  And primitives such as `\expanded` added more recently yet to the engines is not even explained in the e-TeX document.

Comment: TeX in a Nutshell mentions the eTeX, pdfTeX and LuaTeX extensions too. For example `\expanded` primitive is described here too.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to read Czech, then there is [TeXbook inside out](https://petr.olsak.net/tbn.html).

Answer (score 3):

Si vous parlez français, vous peux trouver [how to program in TeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/apprendre-a-programmer-en-tex) chez CTAN.

Translation:

> If you speak French, then you can find ["How to program in TeX"](https://ctan.org/pkg/apprendre-a-programmer-en-tex) on CTAN.

Comment: That's a really interesting one that I've never seen before. For anyone who doesn't speak French, the linked manual is a 500 page book that covers TeX purely as a programming language, without covering typesetting at all.